# Solving $(\frac{1}{9})^x = \sqrt{27}$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, roots, exponentiation

I'm dealing with another silly problem, now with radicals, I've the equation:$$(\frac{1}{9})^x = \sqrt{27}.$$

Working on it:
\begin{align*}
9^{-x} & = 27^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
9^{-x} & = 3^{3\times\frac{1}{2}}\\
9^{-x} & = 3^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
3^{-3x} & = 3^{\frac{3}{2}}
\end{align*}
with exponents:
\begin{align*}
-2x & = \frac{3}{2}\\
x & = \frac{3}{2} \cdot (-\frac{1}{2})\\
x & = -\frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}

But it's not compatible, where's the mistake?

**Edit**

Sorry, it was typo, it's fixed now, but I'm still unable to prove that$$\dfrac{1}{9}^{-\dfrac{3}{4}} = \sqrt{27}.$$

How could I do that ?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo on the line before "with exponents", but it looks like the only real mistake is in the final multiplication.

Comment: (+1) for work shown. @Mike: You should make that an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the new question, you may want to manipulate the exponent in the same fashion you used to get the answer in the first place.

$(\frac19)^{-\frac34}=[(\frac19)^{-1}]^\frac34=9^\frac34=(9^\frac12)^\frac32=3^\frac32=(3^3)^\frac12=\sqrt{27}$

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm so bad working with rationals, thanks;

Answer (score 7):

You made a mistake on one of the last lines (also, in the line before "with exponents" it's $3^{-2x}=3^{\dfrac{3}{2}}$ but I think it's a typo). When you have
$x=-\dfrac{1}{2}.\dfrac{3}{2}$
the product should be
$x=-\dfrac{3}{4}$.